# creating canonical url with using AJAX MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I have url in this manner-

`Home/Index/?Id=234&videotitle=testtitle`

I wanted to convert this url into canonical url, something like this-

`Home/Index/234/testtitle`

**Scenario-**

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {

    <a href="javascript:;" id="video-@Model[i].vd_Id">@Model[i].videoname</a>


    $(function () {
            $('#video-@Model[i].vd_Id').click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/VideoInfo/?vd_Id=@Model[i].vd_Id' + '&videoview=' + '@Model[i].Video_view',
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function (data) {
                        window.location.href = "/Home/Video/ +'" + data.idofthisvideo + "'" + "/" + data.titleofthisvideo
                    }
                });
            });

        });

    </script>

}
```

When I click anchor, It goes to Method-

```
  public JsonResult VideoInfo(long? vd_Id, long? videoview)
        {
            var dataa = (from u in db.Channels
                         select new Addvideo
                        {
                            videoname = dataa.videoname,
                            title = dataa.title,
                            vd_Id = Convert.ToInt64(dataa.vd_Id)
                        }).SingleOrDefault();

            var idofvideo = list.vd_Id;
            var titleofvideo = list.title;
            return Json(new { success = true, viewdata = list, idofthisvideo = idofvideo, titleofthisvideo = titleofvideo });

        }
```

**Note**

I am taking back Id and title through Json result and then trying to change url in manner-

```
success: function (data) {
                            window.location.href = "/Home/Video/ +'" + data.idofthisvideo + "'" + "/" + data.titleofthisvideo
                        }
```

Thereas this calls another method-

```
 public ActionResult Video(long? vd_Id)
          {
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
          return view(someview); 

           }
```

And then it fails with server error and this url-

`/Home/Video/%20+'234'/Test%20title`

```
HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.
```

How can I convert this url into proper canonical url?

Comment: you need to set Url Routes in RoutConfig file

Answer (score 0):

In Url routes (`RouteConfig` class) which is present in **App_Start** directory in asp.net mvc 4 project, add action like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{videotitle}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", 
                                action = "Index", 
                                id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                                videotitle = UrlParameter.Optional  
                              }
            );
```